# Getting the String Text of SelectedItem in Silverlight Listbox (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, listbox

I have a listbox in a Silverlight C# app which is binded to some data from a database in XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
      <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="35" TextAlignment="Left"/>
      <TextBlock x:Name="DetailsText" Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="Gray" Margin="0,-6,0,3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now in code behind file, i am trying to get the string "Name" (binded above) based on the selection user makes in the listbox.

I tried the SelectedIndex property of listbox but it only returns integer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think , ListBox's ItemSource poperty is binded to some custom collection of objects

1- if you handeling selectionchanged event than you can use SelectedItem property

that means

```
CustomObject obj = lstName.SelectedItem as CustomObject


if(obj!=null)

{
   string name = obj.Name;
}
```

where lstName is name of your listbox

and CustomObject is the type of object in the ItemSource property of listbox

Comment: ok i tried this but the object is returning null.

EDIT:

        void client_GetNewsPublishersCompleted(object sender, NewsService.GetNewsPublishersCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            lbStoreMenu.ItemsSource = e.Result;

        }

Comment: private void lbStoreMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<NewsService.News_Publisher> obj = lbStoreMenu.SelectedItem as System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<NewsService.News_Publisher>;

                if(obj!=null)
                { 
                    app.IdNewsStoreSelectedItem = obj.First().Name;
                }

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsStoreDetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

Comment: try this lbStoreMenu.SelectedItem  as NewsService.News_Publisher

Comment: ok ignore my last comment. I have got it to work using the method you wrote. Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the SelectedItem property instead

Edit:
Or even better bind the SelectedItem property to a value in your ViewModel if you use the MVVM pattern in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using , SelectedItem property and if it is not null then try to find the TextBlock with Name as the Child of the SelectedItem using VisualTreeHelper ?